# Does tensor product contain Cartesian product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

This is my first exposure to tensor product on abelian groups and $R$-modules, I am not sure if I understand this correctly.

Given $X \times Y$ and additional structure (abelian groups, vector spaces, $R$-modules) such that bilinearity of function $f: X \times Y \to W$ is defined
$$
    f(a_1 + a_2, b) = f(a_1, b) + f(a_2, b) \text{ and } f(a, b_1 + b_2) = f(a, b_1) + f(a, b_2)
$$

The definition of tensor product $X \otimes Y$ is a map $X \times Y \to X \otimes Y$ such that
$$
    Hom(X \otimes Y, W) \cong Bil(X \times Y, W)
$$
where $Hom$ denotes the class of morphisms from $X \otimes Y$ to $W$ and $Bil$ denotes the class of bilinear morphisms from $X \times Y$ to $W$.

Now, if we take $W = X \times Y$ and $X \times Y \to W$ to be the identity map which is bilinear. By definition of tensor product, the identity map is factored through $X \otimes Y$, namely, the map $X \times Y \to X \otimes Y$ is injective.

That is, tensor product contains Cartesian product.

Comment: Containment as a set or as a module? (i.e. does the inclusion map preserve addition and multiplication?)

Comment: @Trebor I believe that containment of $A$ in $B$ means there is a monomorphism from $A$ to $B$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The identity map $X\times Y\to W$ is **not** bilinear. Writing $f$ for this identity map, $f(a_1,b)+f(a_2,b)=(a_1+a_2,2b)$, which is different from $f(a_1+a_2,b)=(a_1+a_2,b)$.

Also, it is not true in general that $X\otimes Y$ contains $X\times Y$ (as a submodule). In the case of abelian groups, for example, $\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}$, which doesn't contain $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ as a subgroup.

Comment: my mistake. thank you for the clarification